# Implementing a simple adapter for RabbitMq Stream Client in Rust

Tags: rust, rabbitmq

I've been learning rust, and now I'm beginning to write my own learning examples.

I've been trying to create a simple wrapper (producer/consumer) for rabbitMq (The library project is https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-rust-client).

The issue is that I keep getting the error that Stream is not found.

```rust
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: StreamDoesNotExist { stream: "loan_request" }
```

My code for the main is the following:

```rust
mod consumer;

use tokio;
use consumer::{Consumer, BaseCallback};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let loan_request = BaseCallback {data: "{loan_id: 1}".to_string()};
    let consumer_response = Consumer::set_event_callback("loan_request", loan_request).await;
}
```

My code to create a consumer, and a queue is the following:

```rust
use rabbitmq_stream_client::{Environment};
use serde_json;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct BaseCallback {
    pub data: String
}

pub struct Consumer {
    environment: Environment,
    callback: BaseCallback
}

impl Consumer {
    async fn new_connection() -> Environment {
        let environment_instance = Environment::builder()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(5552)
            .build()
            .await.unwrap();
        environment_instance
    }

    pub async fn set_event_callback(event_name: &str, callback: BaseCallback) {
        let connection = Self::new_connection().await;
        let consumer = connection.consumer();
        consumer
            .build(event_name)
            .await
            .unwrap();
    }
}
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The issue is that I keep getting the error that Stream is not found", please post the full error message to make this a [mre]. Your code does not reference `Stream` anywhere.

Comment: I've added the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone wondering, one first needs to create the queue on RabbitMq, for that use the client like this

```rust
let environment = Environment::builder()
        .host("localhost")
        .port(5552)
        .build()
        .await?;

    environment
        .stream_creator()
        .create("loan_request")
        .await
```

Then we can implement the consumer as above to consume, and handle events in the "loan_request" queue.